# Bind escape key to instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, events, keycode

I have been creating my own slide in panel class, I'm really happy with it so far, but I'm wondering how I'd bind the escape key to the current open panel?

I have setup a demo of my plugin:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7PH9g/

I know you can bind events to the keyCode like so:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) { <DO YOUR WORK HERE> }   // esc
});
```

But how would I be able to call `this.sliderClose` from the escape key? What's the best way to access functions outside the class like this?

Basically, I'd like something where I can just hit the escape key, and it would automatically close the panel that's on top automatically. The panel that is on top has a class of infront, and they all have unique ids. but I can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7PH9g/2/

```
 $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
       test.closeSlider();
    }
 });
```

Comment: But that would require me to bind that every time I create a new one, I'd like to create this automatically, and automatically figure out which modal is the top in the list to close.

Comment: See this example. It removes only the upfront modal: http://jsfiddle.net/7PH9g/2/

Comment: I have added that into the bottom of the generateSliders method and it does work, but would you mind explaining to me how it knows what is the top level panel?

Comment: I have added `if ($(self.vars.currentSlider).hasClass("infront")) {` to your `closeSlider` function

Comment: But this event will fire even when the slider doesn't exist anymore, I would just like to know how to bind it to the instance that way when I remove it form the dom the event is destroyed with it.